# what game is it?

Tags: identify-this-game

I got this 2nd hand game/toy from a friend, but he also doesn't know what's the name or company that produce such games:

[image]

The rule is obvious and it's really not easy.

Is there a name for such game? Is there a company producing similar games?

Comment: You might have better luck at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com. Though I don’t know for sure if they allow identification questions, this is definitely more of a puzzle than a board game.

Comment: The concept is similar to the one used in the game Ubongo.

Comment: A similar piece can be seen here in the form of a toy that came with a comic magazine in 2001: https://www.comics.org/issue/330386/cover/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [SmartGames IQ-Puzzler](http://www.smartgames.eu/en/smartgames/iq-puzzler#how-to-play) or a very similar game. The SmartGames version comes with a book of puzzles which start you of with one or more pieces already in the grid, and then you have to fill the rest of the spaces. The easiest puzzles have only three or so pieces to fit, the hardest ones have just one piece already in the grid.

What you may not have realised is that the pieces can also be used to form a square-based pyramid, and there are also a number of puzzles based on completing the pyramid given a starting configuration.

Comment: thx very much! how difficult is the puzzle above?

Comment: @athos that would depend on the player ;)

Comment: @DarkCygnus I mean, just like LEGO, it has a note “4-6 years old”...